# 500 OOPS: vsftpd: refusing to run with writable root inside chroot()

Tags: permissions, ftp, vsftpd

I am fully aware this question was asked countless times, but no solution mentioned before worked for my case.

My config:

```
$ cat /etc/vsftpd-anon.conf 
listen=YES
local_enable=NO
anonymous_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
anon_root=/var/anonftp
xferlog_enable=YES
listen_address=10.0.0.2
listen_port=9988
allow_writeable_chroot=YES
```

See, I am not using any home directory things. There is this one directory I created especially for this case. I also added `allow_writeable_chroot` option and vsftpd recognizes it, but IGNORES IT.

target directory:

```
$ ls -l /var/ | grep anonftp
drwxrwxrwx  3 root root      4096 led 26 11:09 anonftp
```

How I try to use it:

```
$ sudo killall vsftpd 
$ sudo vsftpd /etc/vsftpd-anon.conf &
[1] 21064
$ ftp 10.0.0.2 9988
Connected to 10.0.0.2.
220 (vsFTPd 3.0.2)
Name (10.0.0.2:david): anonymous
331 Please specify the password.
Password:
500 OOPS: vsftpd: refusing to run with writable root inside chroot()
Login failed.
```

Nothing in vsftpd.log

Comment: How did you solve this?

Comment: @sudharma.puranik Please don't laugh, but I installed windows into virtual machine and used FileZilla. It was the best time-effective solution.

Comment: oh I see that was quite a detour :)

Answer (score 2):

Run `echo "allow_writeable_chroot=YES" >> /etc/vsftpd.conf && service vsftpd restart`

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and nothing helped.
not:

1. allow_writeable_chroot=YES  at vsftpd.conf
2. chmod to the ftp root directory

   so I made a strace to the vsftpd process and saw the following lines:

```
...
18825 chdir("/usr/share/empty")         = 0
18825 chroot(".")                       = 0
...
```

after changing the permissions on /usr/share/empty with

```
chmod 0644 /usr/share/empty
```

the error was gone.

Comment: Hours and hours of searching, only the above helped me ... thank you!

Comment: May I ask you how did you make a strace to the vsftpd process?

Comment: strace -p <pid of the proftp process> -f

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "allow_writeable_chroot=YES" >> /etc/vsftpd.conf && service vsftpd restart
```

Run the above command every time when editing conf.

Comment: It's a copy paste of Gilles's answer isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

### SHORT

In my case, with pretty same configuration, problem was that the newly created user didn't had it's own `/home/{username}` directory

### LONG

In `vsftpd.conf`, I had that lines:

```
...
user_sub_token=$USER
local_root=/var/www/$USER
...
```

Not sure, but, it looks like `vsftpd` tries to log user into user's `/home` directory first, then on success it does `chroot()` to `local_root`, and because user didn't had it's own `/home/{username}` directory - it failed with error above.

So, by adding `/home/{username}` directory and setting user as owner - solved it!